# How to force empty Trash if it has system files?

Tags: mojave, trash

The question title may seem a duplicate, but this case of mine is unique. This happened because of this problem, which I was able to answer/solve. https://superuser.com/questions/1447825/will-re-installing-mojave-through-internet-recovery-delete-data

And now the system files of the `Previous Content`, from the previous installed OS cannot be deleted. It seems the MacOS sees these files as legitimate system files, while in fact, they're not.

[image]

I'm using Mojave now btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

- Open the **Trash**, click on it in the **Dock**.
- Open **Terminal** and type the following *command*, followed by a *space*:

  ```
   sudo rm -rf
  ```
- Now drag and drop the *target folder* from the **Trash** onto the **Terminal** window.
- Press **Enter** and type in your (Admin) **password** and press **Enter**.

If that doesn't remove the *target folder*, then make note of its *pathname*, writing it down on a piece of paper.

- Reboot the Mac to the **Recovery HD**, pressing **⌘R**, and holding it, as the computer starts up after having shut it down.
- Once the **macOS Utilities** window appears, select **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu.
- In **Terminal** type the following *command*:

  ```
   rm -rf /path/to/target/folder
  ```

Example:

```
rm -rf /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/johndoe/.Trash/Previous\ Content/Devices
```

- Note: Because this is being done from the **Recovery HD**, you need to add e.g. `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD` to the *pathname* you wrote down earlier.

## **NOTE: Make sure you type the fully qualified pathname correctly as once you press Enter, that's it, it's gone and cannot be recovered!**

- Then type `reboot` and press **Enter**.

---

See: [About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/HT201314)

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel like this would solve my problem so I marked it as an answer. I did a clean install of the Mojave instead. Because, aside from this problem, which this answer could've solved easily, my Spotlight wasn't working even though I tried everything I could read to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue on **Catalina**.

If you are trying to delete a file or directory under protection of SIP([System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)). You should:

1. Enter recovery mode like that answer shows above.
2. Then open `Terminal` and type `csrutil disable` to disable SIP
3. Then restart your original system and delete whatever you want. But be careful to every operation you do with `sudo`!!
4. Enter recover mode again to enble SIP with `csrutil enable`
5. Restart you system.